# Getting different accuracy on test data in MNIST digit recognition in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, classification, mnist

I am doing *handwritten digit recognition* using Keras and I have two files: *predict.py* and *train.py*.

*train.py* trains the model (if it is not already trained) and saves it to a directory, otherwise it would just load the trained model from the directory it was saved to and prints the `Test Loss` and `Test Accuracy`.

```
def getData():
    (X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=10)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
    X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 784)
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 784)
    
    # normalizing the data to help with the training
    X_train /= 255
    X_test /= 255
    
 
    return X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test

def trainModel(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
    # training parameters
    batch_size = 1
    epochs = 10
    # create model and add layers
    model = Sequential()    
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation = 'softmax'))

  
    # compiling the sequential model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
    # training the model and saving metrics in history
    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
          verbose=2,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

    loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
    print("Test Loss", loss_and_metrics[0])
    print("Test Accuracy", loss_and_metrics[1])
    
    # Save model structure and weights
    model_json = model.to_json()
    with open('model.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.write(model_json)
    model.save_weights('mnist_model.h5')
    return model

def loadModel():
    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    model = model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights("mnist_model.h5")
    return model

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = getData()

if(not os.path.exists('mnist_model.h5')):
    model = trainModel(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
    print('trained model')
    print(model.summary())
else:
    model = loadModel()
    print('loaded model')
    print(model.summary())
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
    print("Test Loss", loss_and_metrics[0])
    print("Test Accuracy", loss_and_metrics[1])
```

Here is the output (assuming model was trained earlier and this time model will just be loaded):

> ('Test Loss', 1.741784990310669)
>
> ('Test Accuracy', 0.414)

*predict.py*, on the other hand, predicts a handwritten number:

```
def loadModel():
    json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
    model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    model = model_from_json(model_json)
    model.load_weights("mnist_model.h5")
    return model

model = loadModel()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=10)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 28*28)


loss_and_metrics = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)

print("Test Loss", loss_and_metrics[0])
print("Test Accuracy", loss_and_metrics[1])
```

In this case, to my surprise, getting the following result:

> ('Test Loss', 1.8380377866744995)
>
> ('Test Accuracy', 0.8856)

In the second file, I am getting a `Test Accuracy` of 0.88 (more than double that I was getting before).

Also, `model.summery()` is the same in both of the files:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                50240     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 10)                650       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,890
Trainable params: 50,890
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

I can't figure out the reason behind this behavior. Is it normal? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Didn't you perform any preprocessing before training the model?

Comment: I did. Edited my question(i have now included the complete file)

Comment: And I guess you are using Python 2.x?

Comment: Yes, `Python 2.7.15rc1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discrepancy results from the fact that one time you are calling `evaluate()` method with normalized data (i.e. divided by 255) and the other time (i.e. in "predict.py" file) you are calling it with un-normalized data. In inference time (i.e. test time) you should always use the same pre-processing step you have used for the training data.

Further, first convert the data to floating point and then divide it by 255 (otherwise, with `/`, a true division is done in Python 2.x and in Python 3.x you would get errors when running `X_train /= 255` and `X_test /= 255`):

```
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')

X_train /= 255.
X_test /= 255.
```